# Does it have any issue if I want to add a new column for big table in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

In my project, I am using Cassandra to store huge data. With MYSQL big table it will take a long time to add a new column or index. Will Cassandra solve that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is relatively very easy to add a column and index that column in Cassandra.
Any column added will be propagated to all nodes very fast too. The added column will be initialised with NULL by default

Comment: Do you think that "NULL by default" will take hard disk space?

Comment: Yes, it will, but it would be negligible as compared to actual data. Is it that big a constraint?